# Ubuntu support for Intel Iris 655 video chipset

Tags: video, intel, support

I have an intel NUC8i7BEH which comes with the Intel Iris 655 IGD Viddo chipset.

In the past 01.org used to have an application that would automatically download the latest compiled drivers for intel chipsets, including video support.

It seems that they haven’t updated it since earlier last year so maybe development was halted.  (It worked great for my older NUC with the Intel HD 500 graphic chipset.)

While my video is currently working, I don’t know if the advanced hardware acceleration capabilities are already integrated in Ubuntu (currently I am using 18.10) or if I still have to hope and pray for 01.org support for these drivers.

Soon I will be reinstalling Steam and was hoping that all will be working well in terms of graphics acceleration.

Any thoughts on this?   I scoured the Internet looking for answers, but just saw answers like : “I should probably work” but I was looking for a specific, more informed answer.

Thanks in advance!